# autoencoder only provides linear output

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, accord.net

Hello Guys,

I am working right now on an Autoencoder reducing some simple 2D Data to 1D. The architecture is 2 - 10 - 1 - 10 - 2 Neurons/Layer. As Activation Function I use sigmoid in every layer but the output-layer, where I use the identity.
I am using the Accord.NET Framework to build that.

I am Pre-Training the Autoencoder with RBMs and CD-Algorithm, where I can change the initial weights, the learning rate, the momentum and the weight decay.

The Fine-Tuning is accomplished by backpropagation where I can configure the learning rate and the momentum.

The data is some artificially created shape and is marked green in the picture:

[data + reconstruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT6VK.jpg)

The reconstruction of the autoencoder is the yellow line. Which leads to my problem. Somehow the encoder is not able to create a non-linear shape as output.
Although I tested arround a lot and changed values a dozen times, I am not getting better results. Maybe someone here has an idea how I could find the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look in general any neural network is based on a linear representation for your feature against the output so what the net is actually doing (consider two features) is [w1*x1 + w2*x2 = output].

What you need to do to achieve a non-linear representation is to use extra feature(s) which is a non-linear representation of the old feature(s). Let's say for example use x1^2 as an extra feature or x2^2 or both of them. Hence, the net will give this global equation [w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x1^2 = output] which in nature is a non-linear equation and then you can have a nonlinear representation.

The extra feature equation depends mainly on your data. I have used a quadratic equation in my example but it is not always the correct thing to do. Referring to
[Your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT6VK.jpg) I think you need to use a cos(x) or sin(x) representation.

Comment: He is using a non-linear activation function (sigmoid) which he mentions in his question. So, I think your answer is probably not what the OP requires.